# Find substring which comes in middle or right of any string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace any occurrence of a substring which does not come in left . Like,

1. Input : "ComputerPart"

   Find substring ="t"
   Replace substring ="success"

   *Output* : **CompusuccesserParsuccess**
2. Input : "topaz"

   Find substring ="t"
   Replace substring ="success"

   *Output* : **topaz**                 //t comes at first place (left) of string 'topaz' so it should not be replaced.
3. Input : "questions"

   Find substring ="t"
   Replace substring ="success"

   *Output* : **quessuccessions**                     //this time it should be replaced as 't' found in middle of string 'questions'

Please help me to find a regex pattern in C# for this purpose and any code samples to achieve this.

Comment: `I think these example are enough to make understand to developer.` How will you be financing the development?

Comment: Why doesn't the first "t" in ComputerPart get replaced as well?

Comment: Great question......................... I need regex pattern.

Comment: RegEx is a very heavyweight solution to your problem and probably means the program will run 1000s of times slower than a simple string.replace.

Comment: @Rohit please do not use any offensive statements like "I think these example are enough to make understand to developer" .. i was not able to understand the requirements so is it that i am not a developer ?? .. i am not taking this personally **but please keep in mind this is a universal site and everybody is helping you without gaining anything from your side** ..

Comment: If you have an input string "tarot", is the correct output "tarosuccess" or "tarot"?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for not a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) on the left:

```
\Bt
```

See it [here on regexr](http://regexr.com?36dg0).

`\B` is a zero width assertion that matches when on the left side of a position and of the right side is a word character (or a non word character). So here you have a "t" to the right of `\B`, so it will only match if on the left of the "t" is also a word character.

In other words: It replaces every "t" that is not on the start of a "word".

So I tested it now in c#:

```
string[] myStrings = { "ComputerPart",
    "topaz",
    "questions"
};

Regex reg = new Regex(@"\Bt");

foreach (string str in myStrings) {
    Console.Out.WriteLine(reg.Replace(str, "success") );
}
```

and it produces exactly the same output than regexr:

> CompusuccesserParsuccess
>   topaz
>   quessuccessions

Comment: I have already tried with  this way ,it replaces left most substring of string rather I am looking for any regex pattern which replace middle or right most only ignore left most. Please see the example.

Comment: Have you checked the link I posted? I guess you tried `\b`. I used `\B`, which is the negation. And it produces the results you asked for.

Comment: Yes , but in C# it replaces left most substring only

Comment: TagExpression =  @"\B"+""ComputerPart";

Comment: It is also in c# working as I described I added my test code to my answer.

Comment: Your solution is good but actually it is not working in original project. But in my sample project it works.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
int pos = text.IndexOf("t");
if(pos>0)
   text = text.Replace("t", "Success");
```

Do I get your homework credit :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I can't use this approach as I need to find and replace substring from text file.

Comment: You have tagged this as c#, so I thought you were writing a program.  I have given you a clue as to what to write for your assignment.  Show us what you have done and we'll help you some more.

Comment: See I have used tagged Regex.

Comment: This won't work correctly if you have an input string like "tarot" where the first character is a `t` (so replace is skipped) but there are later characters that *should* be replaced.

Comment: The spec doesn't mention this edge case, so the solution doesn't support it.  Maybe the specifier needs to think of more test cases?

Answer (score 0):

I want more homework credit this time!

```
string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
string[] lines = readText.Split(Environment.NewLine);
string output;

foreach(string line in lines)
{
    int pos = text.IndexOf("t");
    if(pos>0)
       text = text.Replace("t", "Success");

    output += text + Environment.NewLine;
}

File.AppendAllText(newPath, output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you need,

```
string[] inputstrings = { "ComputerPart", "topaz", "questions" };//An array of input strings to manipulate.
string output = "";
Regex rgx = new Regex("t");//Regex pattern to match occurence of 't'.
foreach (string inputstring in inputstrings)//Iterate through each string in collection.
{
  output = rgx.Replace(inputstring, "success", int.MaxValue, 1);//Replace each occurence of 't' excluding those occurring at position [0] in inputstring.
  MessageBox.Show(output);//Show output string.
}
```

What I've done is :

- Loop through each string in collection.
- Match each string against the regular expression for any occurrences of 't'.
- The search begins at position 1 in the array of characters derived from each string.So it
  automatically leaves any occurrence of 't' at start of string.

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/k0W5BY) sample.

Hope it helps you.